# setListAdapter for twitter fabric

Tags: android-studio, android-adapter, twitter-fabric, twitter-timeline

I am trying to make an app with a twitter timeline an android studio. To do this I am using the twitter fabric API. The documentation for that I am following is found at https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-timelines.html#timeline-builders. The problem I am having is that the *setListAdapter* in 
**setListAdapter(adapter);** is coming up with an error saying "cannot resolve method 'setListAdapter(com.twitter.sdk.tweetui.TweetTimelineListAdapter)'". I really have no experience with android studio, so I've copied and pasted most of this code. I've looked up how adapters work in android studio, and I get what they do, but I'm not sure how they're set up. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.Tweet;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.SearchTimeline;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TimelineResult;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TweetTimelineListAdapter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.UserTimeline;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.CollectionTimeline;


public class FeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);

        final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_layout);
        final SearchTimeline timeline = new SearchTimeline.Builder()
                .query("#fblaoutfit")
                .build();
        final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(this)
                .setTimeline(timeline)
                .build();
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                adapter.refresh(new Callback<TimelineResult<Tweet>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<TimelineResult<Tweet>> result) {
                        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                        // Toast or some other action
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's the XML if it will help you at all:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="No Tweets"/>

    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="#e1e8ed"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to study more on using `ListViews` and `ListActivities` in android.

### Cause of Error

Your troubling method `setListAdapter(adapter)` is available in a `ListActivity` but your activity class is `AppCompatActivity`. There is no `setListAdapter(adapter)` method defined in `AppCompatActivity`. That is why you get the above error.

### Solution

By considering rest of your implementation, it is fine that you use `AppCompactActivity`. But then you can't use the `setListAdapter(adapter)` method. Instead you need to get a reference to your `ListView` in your layout and set the adapter for the `ListView` as in below code snippet.

```
public class FeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);

        final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(this)
            .setTimeline(timeline)
            .build();

        //obtain reference to the list view
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //set the adapter to list view
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //your rest of the code
    }
}
```

Also change the `id` of your ListView in layout file as follows.

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/listView"...
```

Comment: Thanks! While I couldn't get your solution to work, changing the activity class to ListActivity did. I actually need to study more android, I've really only been using android studio for a week, it's nothing like unity. :)